# How can I change the state of a button from another page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm working on a site that has some strict specifications. I'm interested to know if what I'm trying to achieve is possible and if yes, how.

I have a page displaying a list of products and a button next to each one called `Reserve`. I get the information from a MySQL database. The code is something like this (it's not the actual code):

```
while($obj = $results->fetch_object()) {
    echo '<div class="product">'; 
    echo '<iframe name="votar" style="display:none;"></iframe>';
    echo '<form method="post" action="reserve.php" target="votar">';
    echo $obj->description.' <button class="reserve" >Reserve</button>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="barcode" value="'.$obj->bar_code.'"/>';
    echo '</form>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Notice the `iframe` there. I use this because when the button `Reserve` is clicked, the page is **not** supposed to be refreshed.

The `reserve.php` page contains the following:

```
if (isset($_POST["barcode"])) {
    $barcode = filter_var($_POST["barcode"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $results = $mysqli->query("UPDATE devices 
                              SET status='reserved' 
                              WHERE bar_code=".$barcode);
}
```

Now, the actual question that I have is: Is it possible to click that `Reserve` button, not refresh the page, but still change the button to the disabled state? I figured that the disabling action should be done from the `reserve.php` hence the question title.

If not, please advise me. What I'm trying to achieve is, when a user scrolls down the product page and clicks `Reserve`, I want the button to become disabled. I wouldn't mind the refresh per se, but what I mind is that when the refresh happens, the user is sent back to the beginning of the page and has to scroll down again if he wants to reserve another product.

Comment: It seems like you really want javascript? Ajax to send the form, and then just set the disabled property of the button.

Comment: use jquery or javascript

Comment: And how do I set the disabled property of the button without refreshing the page?

Comment: check this, if you want disable button when key press, http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/2Nfu4/

Comment: @Zeeshan, when I click the button, I want it to become disabled **and** perform an action

Comment: @Florina, if you want to perform server side action, create javascript function and call onclick to button then disable that button and send ajax request, once get ajax response then enalbe or disable,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `ajax`... it is the possible solution to update the value in db without refreshing the page

```
<input type='button' name='reserve' onclick='return doReserve(your_primary_key)' value='reserve' />
```

Now consider below javascript function to fire an ajax call

```
function doReserve(id)
    var data= {id: id};
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax_reserve.php",
                data: data,
                type: "GET",
                success: function(html) {
                     if(html=='ok')
                    {
                         $('#reserve').prop('disabled', true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      alert('There was some error')
                    }
                }
            });
         }
```

and now create a php file `ajax_reserve.php`

and put your database update code there in that file

```
$update= 'your update check variable i.e true or false';
if($update)
{
    echo 'ok';
}
else
{
    echo 'error';
}
```

let me know if any further help needed

Comment: First of all, thank you for answering! I tried your suggestion and the Ajax function doesn't even seem to be called (I added an alert after the header). You have any idea why this might be happening? From my knowledge, the function should be placed in the `head` part of my html document, in between of `<script>` tags.

Comment: @Florina yes.. that should be in the `<script type='text/javascript'></script>` tag... and place this function at the end of the page before `</html>` tag..